# How to avoid this deprecation warning from a logical statement in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tkinter, basler

I am developing a GUI of 4  using Basler cameras. Within my program, I am facing two problems that cause the GUI to fail to run properly. However, The main goal is to save 4 images based on the camera index. I was told to use the multi-threading technique to develop the GUI, and these are the problems I encountered. These are the codes:

```
def LiveThread(strIdx):
        CamIdx = int(strIdx)

        try:
            panel[CamIdx] = None
            image[CamIdx] = []
            # Start Grabbing
            camera[CamIdx].StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly)
            print("Cam",CamIdx,': Start Grabbing')
            
            iterator = 0

            while bLiveThraed[CamIdx]:
                grabResult = camera[CamIdx].RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException)

                if grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
                    image[CamIdx] = converter[CamIdx].Convert(grabResult) # Access the openCV image data
                    image[CamIdx] = image[CamIdx].GetArray() # change them to an array for easy access

                    if(image[CamIdx] != []):
                        image[CamIdx] = cv2.cvtColor(image[CamIdx], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        image[CamIdx] = cv2.resize(image[CamIdx], (345,270))
                        image[CamIdx] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(image[CamIdx]))

                        if panel[CamIdx] is None:
                            panel[CamIdx] = tk.Label(image=image[CamIdx])
                            panel[CamIdx].image = image[CamIdx]
                            panel[CamIdx].pack(side="left")
                            panel[CamIdx].place(x=(345*CamIdx)+(20*CamIdx)+20, y=100)
                            
                            panel[CamIdx] = tk.Label(image=image[CamIdx])
                            panel[CamIdx].image = image[CamIdx]
                            panel[CamIdx].pack(side="bottom")
                            panel[CamIdx].place(x=(345*CamIdx)+(20*CamIdx)+20, y=400)
                            #cv2.imwrite('./trial/camera'+str(CamIdx)+str(iterator)+'.jpg', image[CamIdx])
                            #iterator +=1
                        else:
                            panel[CamIdx].configure(image=image[CamIdx])
                            panel[CamIdx].image = image[CamIdx]
                        
                else:
                    print("Error: ", grabResult.ErrorCode)
        
                grabResult.Release()

        except genicam.GenericException as e:
            # Error handling
            print("An exception occurred.", e.GetDescription())
```

1. The deprecated warning is displayed in the following image

[image: error]

2. The problem of saving every image corresponding to its camera index like camera00, camera10, camera20, camera30 after executing the `cv2.imwrite('./trial/camera'+str(CamIdx)+str(iterator)+'.jpg', image[CamIdx])`. The resulting error is given in the following image.

[image: error term]

The resulting GUI is as shown in the image attached below.

[image: GUI]

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages. They are hard to read. Post the actual text.

Comment: Sorry for any inconveniences that I might have caused, but when you click the image, you can easily read without any problems. By the way, It won't be repeated anymore.

Comment: don't use `[]` as a sentinel. use `None`. test with `is None`, not equality comparison.

Comment: [Here's a reason why the images should still be replaced by text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In below code, the last line assign `image[CamIdx]` from opencv image to become `ImageTk.PhotoImage` which cv2 can not write down. Consider storing `image[CamIdx]` to another varible before assigning `image[CamIdx] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(image[CamIdx]))`.

```
if(image[CamIdx] != []):
                        image[CamIdx] = cv2.cvtColor(image[CamIdx], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        image[CamIdx] = cv2.resize(image[CamIdx], (345,270))
                        image[CamIdx] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(image[CamIdx]))
```

To

```
save_img = None
if(image[CamIdx] != []):
                        image[CamIdx] = cv2.cvtColor(image[CamIdx], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        image[CamIdx] = cv2.resize(image[CamIdx], (345,270))
                        save_img = image[CamIdx]
                        image[CamIdx] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(image[CamIdx]))
cv2.imwrite('img.jpg',save_img)
```

For the deprecation warning, in case the OP want to check for None image, as Christoph Rackwitz pointed out in the comments: `don't use [] as a sentinel. use None. test with is None, not equality comparison.`

Comment: glad you find it helpful :)

Comment: @maclan, It could take me some time to figure it out. By the way how about the deprecation warning, how can I avoid it? do you have any idea?  after using this code `(image[CamIdx] != [])`

Comment: what deprecation warning? Usually we can just ignore them. Is image[CamIdx] a image or a list? if it is a image then `image[CamIdx] != []` will always be True

Comment: `257: Deprecation warning: elementwise comparison failed. This will raise an error in future` Such kind of a warning on `image[CamIdx] != []`

Comment: in case you want to make sure `image[CamIdx]` is not empty image, try: `image[CamIdx] != [0,0,0]` or `image[CamIdx] != None`

Comment: Thanks for all the trials, however, all the options are not working, they throw an error that suggests using `a.any()` 0r `a.all()`. All in all the concerned problem was solved.

Comment: do not use `[]` as sentinel/placeholder value. just use `None` and test with `is None`. all the other advice on that part of the question is bad.